# Asp.net mvc javascript client validation not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, client

Here is my layout page href links.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="∼/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="∼/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="∼/Content/ErrorStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="∼/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="∼/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="∼/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
```

The page is rendering the proper data-val=true and data-val-required error messages which is passed by data annotations in my cs class when I view source. Nothing is displayed on the page though.

Here is my html beginform within my Edit view.

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin: Edit " + @Model.Name;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
    HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
}

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>Edit @Model.Name</h3>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="panel-body">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProductID)
            @foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
            {
                if (property.PropertyName != "ProductID")
                {
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>@(property.DisplayName ?? property.PropertyName)</label>
                        @if (property.PropertyName == "Description")
                        {
                            @Html.TextArea(property.PropertyName, null, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 5 })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        }
                        @Html.ValidationMessage(property.PropertyName)
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: you might need to use the strongly typed helpers instead, i'm not sure. try replacing your html helpers with the `For` equivalents: `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PropertyName, new { ... })`

Comment: I've tried this in my login page and it still is not working.
'@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary()
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Name:</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password:</label>
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class= "form-control"})
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        }'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

in your web.config?

also css:

```
.field-validation-error
{
  /* label classes */
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;

  /* label danger classes */
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
```

On models example:

```
[Required()]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password {
    get { return passwordValue; }
    set { passwordValue = value; }
}
```

Comment: '<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="Email.WriteAsFile" value="true" />
  </appSettings>'

These are my app settings. They are true...I am thinking there is an incompatible javascript library or something... I have no clue.

Comment: Do you have css defined for it?

Comment: '.field-validation-error {color: #f00;}
.field-validation-valid {display: none;}
.input-validation-error {border: 1px solid #f00;
                         background-color: #fee;

}
.validation-summary-errors {font-weight: bold; color: #f00;}
.validation-summary-valid {display: none;}

Comment: Do you have the attribute [Required()] set on your models?

Comment: [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a product name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(0.1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage="Please enter a positive price")]

Comment: Have you tried using f12 in IE to see if you are getting any javascript errors?

Comment: I figured out the problem. When I copied and pasted the links into my file... the  ' ~ ' symbol was not the same ascii code.
After modifying I have.
'<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>'

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to answer because of a banned account for some unknown reason. If you would like to post the answer with my solution then I will accept it. Thanks.